# Understanding workflows and event receivers

Tags: workflow

Using this article im trying to understand not the when to use either an event reciever or workflow, but what are the justifications. The first one explains do i need to cancel? I have trouble understanding that, so if anyone can explain that would be really helpful. Thank You! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648492.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first decision point in that flowchart is whether you need the ability to prevent the change from being made. With certain event receivers you can prevent the insertion of a new item/updating of an existing item/etc. Workflows always run *after* the change has occurred.

Comment: can you think of why the time thing matters?